# Namespaces and Sub-Namespaces and the libraries they reference in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

Can I have

```
namespace somenamespace
{
//references functionality in DLL_1
      namespace somesubnamespace
      {
       //references functionality in DLL_2
      }
}
```

And if I do this, when I use just somenamespace, will it only include DLL_1 in the solution and if I use somenamespace.somesubnamespace will it include DLL_1 and DLL_2 in the solution?

Or are DLL_1 and DLL_2 set on the project that contains the namespace and no matter which I use, both DLLs will be copied?

Comment: It's worth noting that I have never had the need to nest namespaces in this way, nor have I ever seen libraries that do this, including the BCL. Instead, the namespaces are nested via their naming convention, as in `Namespace.SubNamespace.SubSubNamespace`. But maybe I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above is exactly equivalent to:

```
namespace.somesubnamespace
{

}
```

If you write it your way, or if you write it this way, accessing `somesubnamespace` is done exactly the same way in your code.

Namespaces are essentially just labels to organize your code.  Depending on what your code is accessing will dictate what references you need - but the answer to your question is "no", the references for `namespace` will not necessarily be required.  `namespace.somesubnamespace` is an independent namespace in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add references to the DLLs that your code actually uses (directly or indirectly).

Therefore, if library X has two classes that reference library A and B respectively, and you only use the class that references library A, you do not need library B at all.

Namespaces are organizational concepts and have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you add references to the DLLs, they will be copied. Since you must add the reference in order to use them, both will always be copied.

Comment: Wrong.  You don't need to add a reference to an indirect dependency if you never use it.

Comment: @Slaks - my understanding is that he is asking if using namespaces affects what DLLs are copied to the output directory.